# Accessing local files for a client-side only website, to be distributed as a HTML-download the user opens with a browser

Tags: javascript, html, local, client-side

Due to the safety rules of the same-origin policy (SOP), i am unable to load certain local files when opening an index HTML-file directly with a browser. Using a "live-server"-plugin works fine, as all the files in that case are "on the same *server*". I need to distribute the website as a client-side only *app* - A folder and html file to be opened with your browser. Solutions to the problem always seem to require setting up a server. Is there any way to avoid that, and keep everything on the client?

I am making a mathematics e-book, that i want to distribute as a website people can download. I want it to be client-only and a download, since *if* it were to become popular, then i wouldn't be able to afford running the server (as i would be studying at that time). I have chosen html and javascript over EPUB, as they are much more powerful, and allow for tons of interactivity (and much more efficient development).

So far i have a *browser.html* file, that loads individual pages with JQuery `.load()`. This *browser.html* file has both html, and javascript. The CSS is in an external file. The individual pages have many pictures, that are also stored locally on the server. As the pages are contained in subfolders, the picture URL's go *out* into their parent folder, and *into* the *assets* folder, like: `../../../Assets/Chapter1/Talopgaver og intuition/Misc\F\solsystem.png`. I use custom-elements (shadow-DOM) to handle various complex aspects such as questions, answers, along with certain other things too. Other than JQuery, i also make use of Math-Jax, and a "polymer" library that helps with cross-browser support of custom-elements. All the pages in a certain chapter are loaded in the start, and then put into a array (this makes it fast to scroll through pages as you often do in books). They (as strings) are each modified slightly to automate certain tedious parts of development.

I have tried to open the *browser.html* file on chrome, firefox, internet-explorer, and edge. They all load the html that *browser.html* inherently contains (properly styled even), but none of them load any external pages. Interestingly, one of the images used in the *browser.html* file still works (i would think that would be a local file too, not?). If have tried turning off calls to ajax or external CSS, but nothing changed. I have searched for other people with similair problems, but all the answers just reccomended setting up a server.

When loading the page with a live-server plugin, the result looks something like this:

[*browser.html* page opened with "*live-server*" visual studio code plugin by Dey, Ritwick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBpzM.png)

When opening the *browser.html* page directly using chrome, it looks like this:

[*browser.html* page opened directly with chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNLHK.png)

The error i get (*after* having removed an ajax `.get()` call) isn't particularily descriptive: simply "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" from "platform.js:1". Even if turn off the call to start loading pages, it gives me excaclty the same error messages.

Looking at the network reports, [with live server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ezew.png) it looks very ordinary. [without](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Mf32.png) it's pretty weird. It says it takes hours to load browser.html, even though that clearly isn't the case. It fails loading platform.js, after using 22 seconds trying. The networks report looks a [bit more healthy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr3w2.png) when turning off the call to load pages. It gives up loading platform.js faster (8 seconds), yet still supposedly takes hours to load browser.html.

Though it shouldn't ultimately be neccesary, i have linked the entire *browser.html* document below, along with an example of a page it might load (the example in the first picture above).

[*browser.html*. Too big for a stackexchange code-block embed](https://github.com/BusterLundgaard/browser.html/blob/master/Browser.html)

[*Page in previous picture (page 37)*](https://github.com/BusterLundgaard/browser.html/blob/master/37.html)

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Main problem seems to be the loading of pages using JQuery.load(). Even on a simple testing website that operation is just not possible without running on a server.

Comment: What errors or warnings are you seeing in the browser's console when you try and run your code?

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the heads up. Just updated the post.

Comment: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND likely means your relative paths are wrong. Check what path and protocol it's resolving the URL into and whether that's actually correct and that the file is in that location. You can check the network tab of the developer tools to see all the requests happening and click into them to see the full details of the URL being requested. (You will need to open the network tool before you run the code, as it only logs  things when it's open.)

Comment: @ADyson Didn't know about network request, but just checked it out. The first one with live server looks very typical, but the one without is pretty weird (i've edited in some pictures in the original post). Without the live server, it says that it takes it 6.4 hours to load the browser.html, which isn't what happens. It gives up loading platform.js entirely after 22 seconds (which i guess makes sense since it's for development?). It seems to use all its power trying to load platform.js, cause immedeatly afterwards it loads the rest of the content with no problem. No external pages are loaded

Comment: I think you mixed up which screenshot is which in your description above - you've tagged the "live" one with the picture where it shows 6.4hrs. Anyway, how long did it actually take? And did you click into the platform.js entry to see if it mentions _why_ it failed?

Comment: P.S. I can see in the bigger screenshot that you are loading jQuery twice (both the .min.js and the .js version - they are both the same code, just the .min.js version is compressed to save bandwitdth in a production environment where reading the source code isn't important). You don't need both, so get rid of one of those. Having it loaded twice can cause strange issues sometimes. Also if I'm not mistaken you seem to load platform.js more than once as well.